Hi everybody, how do I add the vercel's analytics function to my project?
I'm basically trying to add the vercel's analitycs function to my project, but, it simply doesn't work and i don't know why.
I just followed the instructions in the documentation, but, it doesn't work. React is installed, the image is my layout.tsx
enter image description here

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

yurrr! i think you've set it up correctly by importing Analytics and placing it in your root layout. but keep in mind, it will only work if your project is deployed on Vercel. make sure the app is actually linked to your Vercel dashboard, otherwise, analytics wont track properly. double-check the deployment and connection to your Vercel account.
Let me know if that helps!
